# Magmi import showing results for prior run

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I have `magento 1.8` and `magmi 0.7.18`.

I have a file that I am using for the imports and I just edit the file and re-save (using the same name), so I dont have to create a bunch of random files.  Im doing some import testing is why im doing that.

When I run the imports, it always shows the import results from the prior run instead of the run that I currently made…

Anyone else experience this?
Why is it doing that and how do I resolve please?

Thanks

Addition to issue:

Ok… just re-run test this way.

```
Price1Change.csv – has 1 record
Price2Change.csv – has 2 records
Price3Change.csv – has 3 records

1.  Restarted computer
2.  Cleared Cache in Chrome
3.  Opened magmi
4.  Using current Default settings, selected “price3Change.csv” file and saved profile at bottom.
5.  Clicked Run Import.  Results showed 3 imported records (correct)
6.  Clicked “Back To configuration” link at bottom of results
7.  Changed file to “price2Change.csv” and saved profile at bottom.
8.  Clicked Run Import.  Results showed 2 imported records (correct)
9.  Clicked “Back To Configuration” link at bottom of results
10. Changed file to “price1Change.csv” and saved profile at bottom.
11. Clicked Run Import.  Results showed 2 imported records and the filename listed was “price2Change.csv” (incorrect).
12. Clicked “Back To Configuration” link at bottom of results
13. Changed file to “price3Change.csv” and saved profile at bottom.
14. Clicked Run Import. Results showed 1 imported records and the filename listed was “price1Change.csv” (incorrect).
```

I repeated that twice just to make sure I wasn’t missing something.  Both times when I ran the import with the price1Change.csv file, it showed results for the prior run “price2Change.csv”.

That made me wonder if it was something with the `SKU` in the `price1Change.csv` file or something, so I closed everything out, cleared cache, and ran magmi just between `price2Change.csv` and `price3Change.csv` multiple times back and forth.
It seemed to work every time.

So then I went back and ran this 14 step process above after closing everything out and clearing cache.
It ran all the way through without issue.
… so that ended me on `price1Change.csv`…

```
I then changed to `price2Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed me results for the prior `price1Change.csv` run I did. (incorrect)

I then changed to `price3Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 3 records imported (correct).

I then changed to `price1Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 3 records imported… results from prior run (incorrect).

I then changed to `price2Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 2 records imported (correct).

I then changed to `price1Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 2 records imported… results from prior run (incorrect).

I then changed to `price3Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 1 records imported and the file as “price1Change.csv” (incorrect).

I then changed to `price2Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 2 records imported (correct).

I then changed to `price1Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 2 records imported… results from prior run (incorrect).

I then changed to `price3Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 1 records imported and the file as `price1Change.csv` (incorrect).

I then changed to `price2Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 2 records imported (correct).

I then changed to `price3Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 3 records imported (correct).

I then changed to `price2Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 2 records imported (correct).

I then changed to `price3Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 2 records imported and the file as `price2Change.csv` (incorrect).
```

I then closed everything out, cleared cache, selected `price2Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, it showed 2 
records (correct).

I then changed to `price1Change.csv`, saved profile, ran import, and it showed 1 record (correct)..

I went back and forth a couple times between `price2Change.csv` and `price1Change.csv` and they showed correct records for a couple rounds and then showed incorrect at some point. I think it was maybe the 3rd time I went from 2 to 1 file…

At one point I thought it might have something to do with a sku in files 1 and 3 b/c it had a leading 0, so I made one more file `price4Change.csv` that has 4 records, none of which have a leading `0 SKU` (and `price2Change.csv` doesn’t have one either).

```
Ran with “price2Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 2 records (correct)

Ran with “price4Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 4 records (correct)

Ran with “price2Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 2 records (correct)

Ran with “price4Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 4 records (correct)

Ran with “price2Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 2 records (correct)

Ran with “price4Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 4 records (correct)

Ran with “price2Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 4 records (incorrect)

Ran with “price4Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 2 records (incorrect)

Ran with “price2Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 2 records (correct)

Ran with “price4Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 4 records (correct)

Ran with “price2Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 2 records (correct)

Ran with “price4Change.csv”, Back to Configuration, showed 4 records (correct)
```

I don’t know what the heck its doing….  Im at a loss.

Yall have any thoughts?

I think its actually making the imports / updates, but its just confusing / scary when you see results that are not for the import you just ran.
And I can run the import twice in a row if I have to on simple product value updates, but I couldn’t run twice if im doing an actual new product import b/c Im guessing that might create duplicates or some other erroneous data…

I have had a couple others say they have experienced this and thought maybe it had to do with the php session, but I really dont have any answers yet.

Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too when I was making a lot of hit-and-trial fixes for a plugin that I wrote to style the description using Markdown. I had a lot of files eventually inside the var/import folder that I did not need at the final stage so I decided to delete them.

When I just kept the last 4 files inside the import folder and ran the import, I experienced an error that said file does not exist and the name it showed on the error was one of the files which was no longer on the server. However, the dropdown showed the correct filename, and next to it, if I clicked download CSV, it downloaded the correct file.

I tried the same as you, save profile, re-run, try a different browser, nothing worked!

At last I just clicked Save Global Profile out of frustration and re-ran the import. It worked! I am not sure if I am too late for posting this answer, but maybe in future someone will save hours of headache with this.